# preg_match for select string like #__james_name

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression for select some text like #__james_name in PHP
I tried with :

```
(^#__[a-z]*)*
```

But I did not succeed.
help please

**UPDATE**
I tried  with :

```
\#__([a-z]*)_([a-z]*)
```

How to using this in preg_match ?

Comment: What input you are giving ? What output you expecting ? Post an example.

Comment: all dear.im test my name is #__james_shepert.Should be select"#__james_shepert"

Comment: Could you share some code and example input, expected output?

Comment: You need to give more details. What is not allowed? Do you always need two sequences with letters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(^#__[a-z_]*)/', '#__james_name', $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping is a bit wrong, try

```
^#_(_[a-z]+)*
```

see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38ejv).

`^` is the anchor to the start of the string, you don't want to repeat that. I replaced also the `*` with a `+` inside the group, so it requires at least one letter.

Now the string has to start with "#_" and then there can be 0 or more parts starting with an underscore followed by one or more (lowercase) letters.

This regex will match:

```
#_  
#__a  
#__a_b  
#__a_b_ccccc_d_efadsfaksdjh
```

Answer (score -1):

Do like this

```
$str=preg_replace('/^#__([\w]+)/', '$1', $str);
```